# How to make a Pagination like Google?

Tags: pagination

Anyone worked with pagination here? I need to work with google style. No ajax, jquery or javascript. Just plain PHP

i found different demos in the internet but it is kind of different.

example of what i am looking for.

<< [1] 2 3 4 5 >>

but when i click 5

<< 3 4 [5] 6 7 >>

anyone could point me to this kind of example?

thanks

Comment: you need to give a bit more information regarding page content...but basically you'll have some variable that represents the page you are on, so that you can then set the link destinations accordingly (which could be the same page, but would include the new value of that variable)

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Thanks @Dykam but please do not post unrelated links here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pagination... I hope this will help you :)

```
<table width="200" border="1" class="tbl_news_content" id="results">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $i=0;
                $no=0;
                $hal = $_GET['hal'];
                if(!isset($_GET['hal']))
                {
                    $page = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $page = $_GET['hal'];
                }

                $max_show = 2;// this is the option that how many items do you want to show each page

                $from     = (($page * $max_show) - $max_show);
                $query_banner = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example_tbl ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $from,$max_show") or die(mysql_error());
                    while($show=mysql_fetch_array($query_banner))
                    { 
                        $no++;
                        if(($no%2)==0)
                            $color = '#f2f2f2'; 
                        else
                            $color = '#f9f9f9';
            ?>
                      <tr class="rows" bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>">
                        <td class="no_content"><?php echo $no; ?></td>
                        <td class="banner_content"><?php echo $show['example']; ?></td>
                        <td class="action_content"></td>
                       </tr>
            <?php 
                }
            ?>      
          </tbody>  
        </table>
    </div><!-- end of table_content -->
        <div id="pagination">
            <?php
                $total_results = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Num FROM example_tbl"),0); 

                $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $max_show); 

                echo "<center>"; 

                if($hal > 1){ 
                    $prev = ($page - 1); 
                    echo "<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?hal=$prev>← Previous </a> "; 
                } 

                for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++){ 
                    if(($hal) == $i){ 
                        echo "$i "; 
                    } else { 
                        echo "<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?hal=$i>$i</a> "; 
                } 
                }
        // Build Next Link 
                if($hal < $total_pages){ 
                    $next = ($page + 1); 
                    echo "<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?hal=$next>Next →</a>"; 
                } 
                echo "</center>"; 
        ?>
    </div><!-- end of pagination -->
```